# Redirect users with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory, subdomain

I want to redirect users to another domain name when they visit a certain directory in my website. For example; if the user visits **/files** then it would redirect them to **www.myfiles.com**. However, I would also like to do the same with subdomains so that when the user goes to **/files** or **files.domain.com** they are redirected to **www.myfiles.com**, for example.

How can I do this in a .htaccess file?
I hope people can understand what I am trying to describe.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 Redirect 301 /files http://www.myfiles.com
```

Comment: Hi you can have one permanent redirect at a time so above will do the trick for folder based redirection. For domain redirection read my blog post here http://jaspreetchahal.org/how-to-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another-htaccess/.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your `domain.com` site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if either files.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^files\.domain\.com$ [NC,OR] 
#or  /files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files$ [NC] 
#redirect to www.myfiles.com
RewriteRule ^  http://www.myfiles.com [L,R=301]
```